# Use non-module library in TypeScript with Rollup

Tags: typescript, rollup

I have a TypeScript application which uses a 3rd party library which provides a global function. As the library is not a module, I am using `@rollup/plugin-legacy` to include it within my application.

This works fine, however my editor (Visual Studio Code) complains that the library is not a module as it has no knowledge of the build process. I can fix this by adding

```
export default libraryFunction;
```

to the bottom of the library file, however I would rather not modify the library if possible.

Is there a way of informing TypeScript that there will be an export in place when the file is built? Ideally I would also like code completion for the library functions as the library has detailed JSDoc comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the library is in the file `library.js` and contains the function `libraryFunction` then create a new file `library.d.ts` in the same directory with the following content:

```
export default libraryFunction;
```